# To prove $\sin(n)$ is divergent using these identities

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The objective is to prove that $\sin(n)$ is divergent.

In my textbook the hint is given as

> If $\sin(n)$ converges, $\sin(n+2) - \sin(n) \to 0$, use the trignometric identities $$\sin A - \sin B = 2 \sin \frac{A-B}{2} \cos \frac{A+B}{2}$$ $$\cos A - \cos B = 2 \sin \frac{A+B}{2} \sin \frac{B-A}{2}$$

##### I tried

Let $\sin n \to a \implies sin^2n \to a^2$ by using the identity $\sin^2 x +\cos ^2 x =1$ we can conclude that $\cos n \to \sqrt{1-a^2}$

and since  $\sin(n)$ converges to $a$, $\sin(n+2) - \sin(n) \to 0$ $$\implies \sin(n+2)-\sin(n)=2 \sin 1 \cos(n+1)$$
$$\implies 0=2 \sin 1 \sqrt{1-a^2}$$ $$\implies a^2 = 1$$

But As $\cos n $ is convergent, $\cos (n+2) - cos (n) \to 0$ $$\cos(n+2)- \cos n = -2 \sin (n+1) \sin(1)$$
$$\implies 0 = -2 \sin(1) a \implies a=0$$

so $a = 0$ and $a=1$.

This is a contradiction to the uniqueness of the limit of a sequence and hence we can conclude that $\sin n$ is divergent...

Is My proof correct? If yes, is this what the author expected? or is there any other way to prove using the given hint?..

Comment: You can conclude that $\cos^2 n $ converges, not $\cos n$.

Comment: Yes your answer is correct, it seems like this is most likely what the author intended.

Comment: @copper.hat yes we can... if $x_n \to x$ then $\sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{x}$... it can be easily proved

Comment: @Conor_Meise Thank you for responding ...

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP What if $x_n <0$? You don't know the sign of $\cos n$.

Comment: @copper.hat yes you're correct... So I need to deal with $|\cos n| \to \sqrt{|1-a^2|}$ from that we can do this same argument and proceed... Is this correct now?

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP Yes, that is better.